# How to find which ports are blocked?

Tags: linux, port, nmap

I have root on two machines A and B and I would like to know which ports can't be accessed on B from A.  Is there some way to run a command line application on B that listens on all ports and then run `nmap` from A maybe?  Ports may be blocked by the routers so just checking `iptables` won't be enough.

A simple nmap gives

```
Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-04-18 09:32 BST
Nmap scan report for B (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
Host is up (0.00038s latency).
rDNS record for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: B
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.07 seconds
```

If I just scan port 5900 from A I get

```
nc -v -w 1 B -z 5900
nc: connect to B port 5900 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

And from B I get

```
nc -v -w 1 localhost -z 5900
Connection to localhost 5900 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

Also running nmap from B I get

```
nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-04-18 09:57 BST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00024s latency).
Hostname localhost resolves to 2 IPs. Only scanned 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
53/tcp   open  domain
631/tcp  open  ipp
5900/tcp open  vnc
```

Comment: Is the process on 5900/tcp bound to the external interface, or to loopback? Check output of `netstat -tln` - if it shows Local Address as 127.0.0.1:5900, then the process is not listening on external interface. If it shows 0.0.0.0:5900, then it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `nmap`, there is a difference between a "filtered" and a "closed" port. That should show all non-accessible ports as "filtered" and those where just no one is listening should be listed as "closed".

If you have a mean router in between which answers TCP requests instead of dropping them, you can find out by binding to all ports (**warning**, you could run out of system resources doing this! Maybe try with ~1000 ports at a time):

```
for i in {1..65535} ; do nc -l $i & done
```

Comment: Can you post an example of a port you suspect being blocked? Simply run `nc -l 1111` (on some versions: `nc -l -p 1111`) on B and `nmap -p1111 B` on A to test port 1111.